# Creating a new column based on another column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Quick question - I want to create another column in SQL Server such as:

**Original Table**

```
Type         Amount     LocNum
Chocolate    15         WC-10202-01
Banana       10         WC-35209-22
Vanilla      5          WC-15815-15
```

**Ideal Table**

```
Type         Amount     LocNum          LocNum2
Chocolate    15         WC-10202-01     WC-10202
Banana       10         WC-35209-22     WC-35209
Vanilla      5          WC-15815-15     WC-15815
```

Comment: Specifically, you want to create another column from the value of your table? or you want t create a new column instead.

Comment: As already mentioned, use a computed column. And I have to ask why! If the last 3 characters are not "desired", why are you storing them? If you must store them, do they have a significance that you are overlooking? Are you also making an assumption about the length and format of the values that are possible in LocNum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really need to, you can create a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table).

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD LocNum2 AS ( <your calculation here> );
```

However, unless you need to index on this calculation for some reason, I'd suggest just adding it as a part of your `select` output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use replace and charindex to do this as below:

```
select [Type], [Amount], LocNum, LocNum2 = replace(LocNum,right(LocNum, charindex('-',LocNum,charindex('-',LocNum,1))),'') 
    from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as that:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name column-definition;
```

Comment: So I should prefix with the fact that I am new to SQL as a whole, by the column definition - how would I define I want to keep the locnum but disregard the last 3 characters?

Comment: I miss took your question for how to add a column in a table. The rest replies sum pretty well your need.