# SQL Query : Add values to columns based on other columns

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
Part          Runs          Duration          Date
-------------------------------------------------------
random_1       NULL          20              2020-01-01           
random_2       NULL          1               2020-01-01            
random_3       NULL          4               2020-01-01           
tot_rand       40            NULL            2020-01-01           
random_1       NULL          60              2020-01-02           
random_2       NULL          12              2020-01-02            
random_3       NULL          3               2020-01-02           
tot_rand       100           NULL            2020-01-02           
random_1       NULL          9               2020-01-10           
random_2       NULL          4               2020-01-10            
tot_rand       30            NULL            2020-01-10
```

Now instead of NULL values in column `Runs` I want to add the `tot_rand` value for the same `Date`.

So that the result will look like this:

```
Part          Runs          Duration          Date     
-------------------------------------------------------
random_1       40           20              2020-01-01           
random_2       40           1               2020-01-01            
random_3       40           4               2020-01-01           
tot_rand       40           NULL            2020-01-01           
random_1       100          60              2020-01-02           
random_2       100          12              2020-01-02            
random_3       100          3               2020-01-02           
tot_rand       100          NULL            2020-01-02           
random_1       30           9               2020-01-10           
random_2       30           4               2020-01-10            
tot_rand       30           NULL            2020-01-10
```

The reason for this is that in the end I want to create a new column called `All` which will count:

`(Runs - Duration) / Runs`

***Final result***

```
Part          Runs          Duration          Date           All
---------------------------------------------------------------------
random_1       40           20              2020-01-01       0.5
random_2       40           1               2020-01-01       0.975     
random_3       40           4               2020-01-01       0.9    
tot_rand       40           NULL            2020-01-01       NULL    
random_1       100          60              2020-01-02       0.4  
random_2       100          12              2020-01-02       0.88    
random_3       100          3               2020-01-02       0.97    
tot_rand       100          NULL            2020-01-02       NULL    
random_1       30           9               2020-01-10       0.7    
random_2       30           4               2020-01-10       0.86     
tot_rand       30           NULL            2020-01-10       NULL
```

I'm working in MariaDB / MySQL environment.

Maybe there is some other way to do this? I'm all open for suggestions.

Comment: Why did you add the Microsoft SQL Server tag if you are using MariaDB / MySQL?

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43926868/creating-a-new-column-based-on-another-column-in-sql-server

Comment: I don't have admin privileges but can only query the table. Is there anyway to get the results by querying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(runs, max(runs) over (partition by date)) as imputed_runs
from t;
```

If you specifically wanted the `'tot_rand'` value, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(runs,
                 max(case when part = 'tot_rand' then runs end) over (partition by date)
               ) as imputed_runs
from t;
```

If you wanted an `update`, then one approach is:

```
update t join
       (select date, max(runs) as max_runs
        from t
        where part = 'tot_rand'
        group by date
       ) tt
       on t.date = tt.date
    set runs = tt.max_runs
    where tt.runs is null;
```

The subquery may not require aggregation, but it is unclear if there can be more than on `'tot_rand'` value on a given date.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.Part, t2.Runs, t1.Duration, `Date`, 1 - t1.Duration / t2.Runs `All`
FROM test t1
JOIN test t2 USING (`Date`)
WHERE t2.Part = 'tot_rand'
```

Only one row for each `Date` value must contain `Part = 'tot_rand'`.

The value of `Runs` will be replaced even if it is not NULL. Or you may use original `t1.Runs` but `t2.Runs` or `COALESCE(t1.Runs, t2.Runs)` in `All` calculation.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=440969fc417980aa3688bb4dac67bab2